# MediaPlayer doesn't always play

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I cannot figure out why `MediaPlayer` sometimes plays and sometimes doesn't play the same file. There are ca. 2000 audio files in the directory. It can happen to any of them. By the next app run it can be some other files that are affected. I have no explanation to this.

Below is the code:

```
private void play(List<Integer> lineIndices, final MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener) {
    Log.d("ENTER lineIndices.size()=", lineIndices.size());

    File sdcard = (RUNS_ON_EMULATOR) ? Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() : new File("/storage/sdcard1");

    final List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer index : lineIndices) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard + DEFAULT_FOLDER + getFileName(index)));
        Log.d("File URI=%s", uri.toString());
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
        players.add(player);
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < players.size() - 1; i++) {
            players.get(i).setNextMediaPlayer(players.get(i + 1));
        }

    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            completionListener.onCompletion(mediaPlayer);
            for (MediaPlayer player : players) {
                player.release();
            }
        }
    };

    if (!players.isEmpty()) {
        players.get(players.size() - 1).setOnCompletionListener(listener);
        Log.d("Before players.get(0).start();");
        players.get(0).start();
    }

    Log.d("EXIT");
}
```

The log output shows that the file is determined and `players.get(0).start()` is called:

```
com.android.vocabularytrainer D/VocabularyTrainerModelImpl: [play] ENTER lineIndices.size()=
com.android.vocabularytrainer D/VocabularyTrainerModelImpl: [play] File URI=file:///storage/sdcard1/tmp/english/vocabulary/000010.wav
com.android.vocabularytrainer D/VocabularyTrainerModelImpl: [play] Before players.get(0).start();
com.android.vocabularytrainer D/VocabularyTrainerModelImpl: [play] EXIT
```

I tried to solve it by using only one `MediaPlayer` instance, not using `setNextMediaPlayer` method and introducing method calls `setDataSource(), prepare()` and `reset()`. It improved the situation a little, but it can still happen that a file won't be played. However it happens not so often as earlier.

```
private void play(final List<Integer> lineIndices, final MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener) {
    Log.d("ENTER lineIndices.size()=%d", lineIndices.size());

    if (!lineIndices.isEmpty()) {
        final File sdcard = (RUNS_ON_EMULATOR) ? Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() : new File("/storage/sdcard1");

        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard + DEFAULT_FOLDER + getFileName(lineIndices.get(0))));

        try {
            player.setDataSource(context, uri);

            MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                private int i = 1;

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    if (i < lineIndices.size()) {
                        final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard + DEFAULT_FOLDER + getFileName(lineIndices.get(i++))));
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    Log.d("%s", uri.toString());
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                }
                            });
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            return;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("Unable to play file", e);
                        }
                    }

                    completionListener.onCompletion(mediaPlayer);
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            };

            player.setOnCompletionListener(listener);

            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Log.d("%s", uri.toString());
                    player.start();
                }
            });
            player.prepare();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Unable to play file", e);
        }

    }

    Log.d("EXIT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, It looks like out of memory issue. Issue happen randomly? Memory issue does. Limit number of mediaPlayers in app and manage them carefully (2 or 3) . Don't prepare media too much. If I'm correct - MediaPlayer.create() will prepare media on creation which will consume memory.

**UPDATED**

I found that there is no reference for MediaPlayer. Which means that MediaPlayer can be GCed at any time. Normally, mediaPlayer will stop playing when GCed.
Track MediaPlayer with reference.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer; // field Variable
...
private void play(final List<Integer> lineIndices, final MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener) {
    ...
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    ...
```

Comment: Yes. It can happen to any of those 2000 files. Please look at the second version of the method in my answer. I've just added it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't tried to find a solution anymore. I've decided to workaround the problem by using text file and Google TTS instead of thousands of audio files. But regarding mediaplayer, I think some of its functionality isn't reliable (at least in Android 4.2.1). E.g. I've noticed that seekTo() doesn't work well if audio file is 2-3 hours long. I assume that mediaplayer has some problems with playing thousands of files which are only 1-2 seconds long. It may not handle this use case well.